# How to redirect a command's output to a file whose name starts with & (ampersand)?

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping

I'm trying to redirect a command's output to a file called e.g. `&foo.txt`, but nothing I've tried so far works.

The command `echo test > "&foo.txt"` gets interpreted as `echo test >&foo.txt`, and triggers the stream-to-stream redirection syntax (`>&2`). I've tried escaping with `^` to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just hit me:

```
echo test > ".\&foo.txt"
```

Comment: That one's going to bite you eventually because it's also a command separator (which the `^` would escape), unless you're in a tightly controlled environment where you know exactly what's going to happen to it.

Comment: The quotes prevent it from being handled as a command separator.

Comment: Agreed, in this one case.  That's why I pointed it out.  You'll have 1 or more files with a filename that has to be handled specially forever.  But if that's what you want, enjoy!

Comment: Wow, snark much? This question is in relation to a programming language's process creation library, and the library already does all necessary quoting and escaping. I've tested it by generating file names and program arguments with random characters, and all thousands of random tests worked, except for this one case with the `&` as the leading character. Yes, it is a special case, but such is CMD's argument parsing logic.

Comment: Link to patch implementing this fix: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/2503

Comment: Sorry it came across as snarky.  I should have left it alone and not mentioned the potential traps.